# How to send data to windows application using Blackberry sdk

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I'm trying to figure out how to programatically send data back and forth from a Blackberry device to a Windows applications in the same type of manner that BlackBerry Desktop Software does.  I would like to be able to query status of my BlackBerry app and have it send me a data buffer etc.

Answer (score 2):

The device side API you need is the [syncrhonization package](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/synchronization/package-summary.html).

I believe [this document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1093/Desktop_API_Reference_Guide_46.pdf) contains the starting point for writing the PC side of the synchronization.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm on my way to making this work now.  One thing I noticed is that I need bbdevmgr.exe to make the Windows side function but I don't have that on my system even though I've installed the BlackBerry Desktop Software.  Any ideas where I can download it?

Comment: Sorry no. I've never done any work on that side of things. You can probably get an answer at developer support: https://developer.blackberry.com/bdsc/home.html

Answer (score 0):

It is located in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Research In Motion\USB Drivers`